# parLapply inconsistent with lapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a list of `dgCMatrix`, that I'm trying to parallelize a function on.
The `parLapply` is inconsistent --produces correct results for certain indices, and not for others. 
`lapply` is consistent. Any ideas what's wrong?

A dummy example follows:

```
library(Matrix)
library(parallel)
li_coefs<-list("1"=list(Matrix(rep(1:5, each=2),ncol=1) , Matrix(rep(6:10, each=2),ncol=1) ),
               "2"=list(Matrix(rep(11:15, each=2),ncol=1) , Matrix(rep(16:20, each=2),ncol=2), Matrix(rep(21:25, each=2),ncol=2),Matrix(rep(26:30, each=2),ncol=1) ),
               "3"=list(Matrix(rep(101:105, each=2),ncol=2) , Matrix(rep(106:110, each=2),ncol=1), Matrix(rep(111:115, each=2),ncol=1) ),
               "4"=list(Matrix(rep(131:135, each=2),ncol=1) , Matrix(rep(136:140, each=2),ncol=2), Matrix(rep(141:145, each=2),ncol=1) ),
               "5"=list(Matrix(rep(991:995, each=2),ncol=2) , Matrix(rep(996:1000, each=2),ncol=1)))

doThings<-function(thecoefs,v){
  tryCatch({ 
  coefs<-thecoefs[[v]]
  K <- length(coefs)
  for(k in 1:K){
    b<-coefs[[k]]
    if(dim(b)[2]>1) b<-t(b)
    ##do some stuff
  }
  K}, error=function(e) return(paste0("Node ", v, " caused error: ",e)))
}

cl <- makeCluster(numcores)
clusterExport(cl,c("doThings", "li_coefs"))
result.par<- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(v){
 doThings(li_coefs,v)
})
stopCluster(cl)

result<-lapply(1:5, function(v){doThings(li_coefs,v)})
```

The results:

```
> result.par
[[1]]
[1] "Node 1 caused error: Error in if (dim(b)[2] > 1) b <- t(b): argument is of length zero\n"

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] "Node 3 caused error: Error in if (dim(b)[2] > 1) b <- t(b): argument is of length zero\n"

[[4]]
[1] "Node 4 caused error: Error in if (dim(b)[2] > 1) b <- t(b): argument is of length zero\n"

[[5]]
[1] 2

> result
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 2
```

Comment: You need to make sure that `Matrix` is loaded on the workers. I get identical results if I add `require(Matrix)` to your function.

Comment: Ugh I feel dumb. Thanks it works well. @Roland

Comment: Minor comment: use either `library(Matrix)` or `require(Matrix) || stop("Failed to attach package: Matrix")`.  Using `require()` alone will pass silently even if `Matrix` is not available.